# Magento: Edit “Your credit card will be charged for” on onepage checkout to show desired currency

Tags: magento, currency, checkout

[image]

I think the picture is explaining the problem. I did a research and I simply have not enough time to create another 4 stores and set over 200 articles again and again. I would agree on removing the "Your credit card will be charged for" line completely, or change the functionallity to show the currency which was chosen by the customer.

Answer (score 2):

Comment out the lines that you want to remove in: `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/totals.phtml`

Additionally remove the following code from `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/Totals.php`

```
/**
         * Base grandtotal
         */
        if ($this->getOrder()->isCurrencyDifferent()) {
            $this->_totals[\'base_grandtotal\'] = new Varien_Object(array(
                \'code\'  => \'base_grandtotal\',
                \'value\' => $this->getOrder()->formatBasePrice($source->getBaseGrandTotal()),
                \'label\' => $this->__(\'Grand Total to be Charged\'),
                \'is_formated\' => true,
            ));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The .csv file which you can edit "Your credit card will be charged for" is located in `/app/locale/en_US/Mage_Sales.csv`

Answer (score 0):

First you have to go to the

**admin panel -> System -> Configuration -> CATALOG -> Catalog -> Price -> Catalog Price Scope** and change it **from Global to Website**.

Now when you go to the

**admin panel -> System -> Configuration -> GENERAL -> Currency Setup -> Currency** Options you can **change Base Currency per Website**, not only for Default (Global).

So you have to transfer you stores to websites and you will be able to do what you want.

Answer (score -4):

do you know which .csv to edit "Your credit card will be charged for" ?

UPDATE: FOUND:
it is located in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/totals.phtml